# Write echo output in file when shell execute from os.system

Tags: jython

I am running a shell command through jython os.system command. My code is given below:

```
import os
import sys

vCmdLine = "sh C:/scripts/WAQ.sh PARAM_1 PARAM_2 >> C:/logs/WAQ.log 2>&1"
vCmdRC = os.system(vCmdLine)
```

My shell has several echo commands which I want to get written in `C:/logs/WAQ.log` file.

The code is working fine if I execute the same on unix OS. However when I run the same on windows, it does not write anything in `C:/logs/WAQ.log` file. I am using unix util lib on windows.

What is the issue?

Comment: What is 'unix util lib'?  If you remove Jython from the equation, and simply run `sh C:/scripts/WAQ.sh...` on the command line, does it work as expected?

Comment: @DavidCharles Hi, Sorry I forgot to mention that earlier, yes if I run the command directly from the windows command prompt (cmd) everything works fine and log contains all the echo statements.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a code and replace os.system with subprocess.call and the logging is now perfect. Below is my code

`import subprocess
    vLogFileName = 'C:/logs/WAQ.log'
    vCmdLine = "sh C:/scripts/WAQ.sh PARAM_1 PARAM_2"
    f = open(vLogFileName, "a")
    subprocess.call(vCmdLine, stdout=f)
    f.close()`

Why the logging is not working with os.system on windows?